# Custom onClick list

Tags: unity-game-engine, onclick

Can i create custom region with grouped methods for list `onClick` like dynamic and statics?
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmU9q.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no! ^^

- **Yes**, you can create your own event type taking a parameter and assign dynamic callbacks to it. What you are looking for is [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html).

  For the dynamic parameterized ones see [`UnityEvent<T0>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html) to [`UnityEvent<T0, T1, T2, T3>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_4.html) depending on how many parameters you need.

  For the example with a single `int` it would be (exactly as in the API example)

  ```c#
  // Since Unity doesn't support direct serialization of generics you have to implement this [Serializable] wrapper
  [Serializable]
  public class MyIntEvent : UnityEvent<int>
  {
  }

  public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
  {
      public MyIntEvent m_MyEvent;
  }
  ```

  [image]
- **No**, you can not simply change the existing implementation of [`UI.Button.onClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Button.html#properties) which is parameterless.

  What you could do, however, is build a new component and attach it on a button like

  ```c#
  [RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
  public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
  {
      [SerializeField] private Button _button;
      public MyIntEvent onClickWithIntParameter;

      private void Awake()
      {
          if(!_button) _button = GetComponent<Button>();
          _button.onClick.AddListener(HandleOnClick);
      }

      private void HandleOnClick()
      {
          // Wherever you get your int from
          var value = 123;

          onClickWithIntParameter.Invoke(value);
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that `[Serializable]` isn't working for you try `[System.Serializable]` or `using System;` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

For Those who want to create a custom event Script:

I made a collision detection script. The events set in the inspector are called when a collision is detected. Just like a button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4epP.png

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class CollisionCallFunc : MonoBehaviour {
    [System.Serializable]
    public class CollisionEvent : UnityEvent<object> {
        public object value;
    }

    [SerializeField]
    private CollisionEvent collisionEvents = new();

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        try {
            collisionEvents.Invoke(collisionEvents.value);
        } catch(System.Exception exception) {
            Debug.LogWarning("Couldn't invoke action. Error:");
            Debug.LogWarning(exception.Message);
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        try {
            collisionEvents.Invoke(collisionEvents.value);
        } catch(System.Exception exception) {
            Debug.LogWarning("Couldn't invoke action. Error:");
            Debug.LogWarning(exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```